# Can I make someone see whatever I want them to see?

Tags: brain

If some were to lose their eyes and I was able to send the exact same electrical impulses to their brain as the eye does, would I be able to make them see whatever I wanted them to see?

Comment: Welcome to the site Brent, I don't see anything that particularly makes this related to world-building...if you were to expand it to using some sort of non-existent tech and whether it is feasible that could potentially be on-topic.  I am going to flag to put this on hold, as at the moment it is not on topic for the site.  Getting put on hold is no big deal.  Once the question is altered to be on topic it can be re-opened.

Comment: For more info on the site and how to ask good questions check out the [help] and once you hit 20 rep you will have access to [chat] which is another good way to get help.  Again, welcome to the site.

Answer (score 2):

### Yes

The brain is a big analog pattern recognizer.  If the incoming electrical impulses match patterns held in the brain then the brain would interpret those signals as "real".

### For example

If the sequence '00001' fed to the brain by normal eyes is a spherical cow then feeding '00001' to the brain by electrical wires should still be a spherical cow.  Sending '10000' would be a cubic lion.  (Endian-ness is a really big deal!)

Answer (score -1):

Yes.

The eyes are not magic.  Why would you suppose otherwise?